# Plotting time series with different scales with Hichcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to represent two time series with Highcharts. My problem is that one has large values and the other one low values. When I plot them together, the one with low values appear as a straight line. I want to be able to plot them with two different scales, but find it impossible to do it. I put what I already have here on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S2uyp/), and the code is here:

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
  rangeSelector : {
  selected : 1,
  inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 300,
  enabled:1
  },
  chart:{type:'line'},
  series: [
  {name: 'serie with high values',
  color: 'red',
  data: [1000,2000,3000,4000]
  },
  {name: 'serie with low values',
  color: 'green',
  data: [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]
  },


  ],
  legend: {
  enabled:true,

            },
  })
  });
```

I would appreciate if someone could point me how I could give a different scale to each time series - ideally, I will want to plot more than two, each of them having its own scale.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes)

Comment: @marco - that should be an answer, since using multiple yAxis will allow to have different scales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use to yAxis, like in the example

```
yAxis:[{

     },{
         opposite:true
     }],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S2uyp/1/

Comment: Yes, adding the yAxis and also specifying in for each serie to what axis it relates does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the line `opposite: true` is not needed to have separate scales, although it makes it a bit less messy to read.

Answer (score 0):

As the difference between high values and low values is very high so the chart is looking like this but if you try with the following values then you will see that the chart looks good

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
  rangeSelector : {
  selected : 1,
  inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 300,
  enabled:1
  },
  chart:{type:'line'},
  series: [
  {name: 'serie with high values',
  color: 'red',
  data: [10,15,30,40]
  },
  {name: 'serie with low values',
  color: 'green',
  data: [0.1,1,5,10]
  }],
  legend: {
  enabled:true
  }
  })
  });
```

Comment: That's true, but I want to be able to plot high and low values together and see their variations, as in @marco's link.

Comment: let me try once if I could do anything for you

Comment: if you narrow down from the link provided by S4M, that also looks like your chart    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            legend: {
                enabled:true
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                color: '#AA4643',
                data: [1016, 1500, 2505, 500, 4000, 6000]    
            }, {
                name: 'Temperature',
                color: '#89A54E',
                data: [.2, .5, .9, 50, 100]
            }]
        });
    });

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes) is exactly what you want I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an answer telling you how to accomplish specifically what you asked, let me add one that addresses the issue more fundamentally.

This is a classic example of when what you really need is two separate charts (generally, aligned vertically one above the other works best for line charts, where they can work with a common time axis).

That's a concept that seems to shock some people, but it really is the best solution, and there really is no negative aspect to having two charts instead of one.

The problem with plotting 2 series on one chart, with 2 different scales, is that it practically forces the user to make comparisons that are not real.  When you plot 2 lines on a chart, the interaction of those 2 lines is generally something of importance, and will be seen as such by the viewer.

When the 2 lines have 2 different scales, the interaction is completely meaningless, and the two lines serve only to clutter the chart and obscure the message of the data.

Essentially, when you plot 2 series with 2 separate scales, you *are* making 2 charts already anyway - but you're scrunching them into one space where they get in each others way.

FWIW

{{**UPDATE**:

As an example, here is a fairly typical example of 2 series plotted on separate scales on the same `chart`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/GYbRY/

It could be cleaned up and improved a bit, but overall it's going to be a bit of a mess no matter what you do to it.

Here is the same data plotted on 2 separate charts, in significantly less space than the `original`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/m64Ys/

I feel it's hard to support the argument that the first example makes it easier to compare the variation in the two series.

Comment: Well, I see two reasons to want to plot more than one series of different scales on the same chart: 1) it saves places, 2) it makes it easier to compare the *variations*. YMMV.

Comment: Saving space by obfuscating data is a poor trade.  Better chart design will often allow multiple charts to fit where one used to be.  Comparing variations is just as easy, if not easier, when you have two charts on top of each other with each chart formatted how it needs to be to fit the particular data series.  It is no harder to look at two properly set up line plots than it is to look at 2 lines on one plot.  And if the lines interact on a single plot (which is meaningless with 2 scales), it is, in fact, more difficult to accurately compare the 2.